# Accessing a C# dictionary in Python.NET : TypeError: cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence

Tags: python, c#, python.net

I'm stuck trying to access a C# Dictionary from some Python code using Python.NET.

Trying to explicitly create a Python `dict` from a C# Dictionary fails with a `TypeError: cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence` error:

```py
import clr

clr.AddReference('System')
clr.AddReference('System.Collections')

from System.Collections.Generic import Dictionary
from System import String
from System import Object

d = Dictionary[String, Object]()
d['Entry 1'] = 'test'
d['Entry 2'] = 12.3
print(f" d.Count : {d.Count}") # returns 2

py_dict = dict(d)
```

```
 d.Count : 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_dict.py", line 21, in <module>
    py_dict = dict(d)
TypeError: cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence
```

In my real code the `c_sharp_obj` Dictionary is being declared as:

```cs
Dictionary<DescriptorType, IDescriptor> Descriptors { get; }
```

`IDescriptor` is a custom C# class:

```cs
public interface IDescriptor : IDisposable
```

And `DescriptorType` is an `enum`:

```cs
public enum DescriptorType
{
  CharacteristicAggregateFormat   = 0x2905,
  CharacteristicExtendedProperties = 0x2900,
  CharacteristicPresentationFormat = 0x2904,
  CharacteristicUserDescription = 0x2901,
  ClientCharacteristicConfiguration = 0x2902,
}
```

On IronPython I could iterate over the key and values with

```
for k, v in  in dict(c_sharp_obj).iteritems():
```

If I try:

```py
print(c_sharp_obj)
print(type(c_sharp_obj))
```

I get:

```
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[DescriptorType,IDescriptor]
<class 'System.Collections.Generic.313, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]'>
```

I can iterate over the Dictionary with:

```
for k in c_sharp_obj:
    print(k)
    print(type(k))
```

And I get:

```
[CharacteristicUserDescription, Type:CharacteristicUserDescription]
<class 'System.Collections.Generic.313, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]'>
```

Shouldn't I get `DescriptorType` as the type? If I try to index the Dictionary with the key:

```py
print(c_sharp_obj[k])
```

I get a `TypeError: No method matches given arguments: (<class 'System.Collections.Generic.313, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]'>)`.

I was able to access the enum value with:

```py
enum_name = str(k).split(',')[0].replace('[', '')
enum_value = System.Enum.Parse(clr.GetClrType(Arendi.BleLibrary.Service.DescriptorType), enum_name);
print(hex(enum_name))
print(c_sharp_obj[enum_name])
```

But the line `print(c_sharp_obj[enum_name])` gives me `Type:CharacteristicUserDescription` and not a `IDescriptor` object.

How can I iterate over the C# Dictionary accessing the original C# classes?

I'm using Python.NET 2.5.2. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3):

The generic type `System.Collections.Generic.313` you are seeing when iterating over .NET dictionary using Python.NET is propbably an instantiation of [`KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyvaluepair-2). So in your loop you can access `k.Key` and `k.Value`. Which, BTW, you could have discovered by running `dir(k)`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Indeed, I can create a Python dictionary using `python_dic = {v.Key: v.Value for v in d}`.